# C#: assign array with params argument

Tags: c#, parameters, params-keyword

What speaks against doing this?:

```
public struct T
{
    private float[] Elements { get; set; }

    public T(params float[] elements)
    {
        Elements = elements;
    }
}
```

Could this possibly lead to undefined behaviour? Or will the garbage collector keep the array alive since it is beeing used?

Comment: That looks perfectly legal. What are you concerned about?

Comment: Hint: arrays are reference types. What happens if you replace `float[]` with a class type (and remove the `params`)?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I might just be used to c++ where you need to keep track of everything yourself. And relying on something that was not created by yourself feels...dirty? `new T(float1, float2, float3...);` does not feel like creating an array. But might just be unneccessary concerns

Comment: The `params` doesn't make any difference here at all: `params` makes the compiler construct an array to pass into your method if necessary, but your method still receives a normal array regardless of `params`

Comment: Yeah, get out of that C++ mindset :) Shared ownership of objects is normal and expected in C#, and the GC takes care of it

Comment: @JoeSewell good point. I was just unsure about the context. But as I said. Might just be a habit I took from C++

Comment: "lead to undefined behaviour" No, it **is** defined. However it may lead to **unexpected** behaviour, depending on what your mindset is - and apparently it´s a C-background, which *will* make a difference.

Comment: @canton7 alright! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide an answer and add some details.

This is perfectly legal. The compiler will in effect transform

```
new T(1, 2, 3)
```

To

```
new T(new float[]{1, 2, 3})
```

Since arrays are reference types the constructor will just assign a reference. And since references are tracked by the garbage collector there is no risk for a memory leak or other issues that may affect c++.

From the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) (Emphasis mine)

> Within a method that uses a parameter array, **the parameter array behaves exactly like a regular parameter of an array type**. However, in an invocation of a method with a parameter array, it is possible to pass either a single argument of the parameter array type or any number of arguments of the element type of the parameter array. In the latter case, an array instance is automatically created and initialized with the given arguments.

Comment: It might be good to notice that in the question's context, the values inside Elements can still be changed from the outside, eventhough it is private. `float[] values = new float[] {5, 6};` and `T t = new T(values);` with a following `values[0] = 7;` will result in Elements beeing changed. As this is normal expected C# behaviour it is not an answer to the question imo. But I thought it might be noteworthy.